# Return true/false for a matched/not matched regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex on Javascript

```
var myS = "00 - ??:??:?? - a";
var removedTL = myS.match(/^(\d\d) - (\?\?|10|0\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d) - (.*)/);
```

and I need to return "false" if `myS` is not in that format, true otherwise.

I mean :

```
var myS = "00 - ??:??:?? - a";  // TRUE
var myS = "00 - ??:?:?? - a";   // FALSE
```

how can I check if the regex has matched the string or not?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `match` method will return `null` if there is no match.

Comment: So how does this convert to `true/false`?

Comment: `null == false`? I don't think so, sir!

Comment: This is not the best answer. RegExp.prototype.test() is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 162):

The more appropriate function here might be `RegExp.test`, which [explicitly gives you true or false](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

```
console.log(/lolcakes/.test("some string"));
// Output: false

console.log(/lolcakes/.test("some lolcakes"));
// Output: true
```

Answer (score 26):

Use a double [logical NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

```
return !!removedTL;
```

This will convert to `true/false` depending on if matches are found.

No matches gives you `null`, which is converted to `false`.

One or more matches gives you an Array, which is converted to `true`.

---

As an alternative, you can use `.test()` instead of `.match()`.

```
/^(\d\d) - (\?\?|10|0\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d) - (.*)/.test( myS );
```

...which gives you a boolean result directly.

Comment: Not going to lie, the !! will lose a good chunk of people. Cool trick though. +1 for using some sweetness.

Comment: @Jackson: Could be. I tend to assume that people are familiar with `!!`, but I probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 9):

```
var myS = "00 - ??:??:?? - a";
var patt = new RegExp("^(\d\d) - (\?\?|10|0\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d) - (.*)");
var removedTL = patt.test(myS);
```

removedTL will hold a boolean value true if matched, false if not matched

Comment: In addition to the code a few words explaining that `removedTL` will hold a boolean value would make this answer more helpful.

Comment: What does this answer add over the others that were posted three _years_ prior?

Answer (score 1):

Since I also prefer using *match* you could do the following workaround to get a Boolean result:

```
var myS = "00 - ??:??:?? - a"
var removedTL = myS.match(/^(\d\d) - (\?\?|10|0\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d) - (.*)/) != null
```